# Uncaught File 'OpenSans-Italic.ttf' not found in virtual file system. how to generate pdf files using pdfMakejs library?

Tags: javascript, pdfmake

index.html

```
<html>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>
      <script src="js/main.js"></script>
      <script src="js/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

This main.js has pdfMake library.

createPdf.js

```
var pdfContent = function() {
    content: [
        { text: 'This paragraph will have a bigger font', fontSize: 15 }
    ],
    defaultStyle: {
        italics: true,
        font: 'openSans'
    }
};

pdfMake.fonts = {
    openSans: {
        normal: 'OpenSans-Light.ttf',
        bold: 'OpenSans-Bold.ttf',
        italics: 'OpenSans-Italic.ttf',
        bolditalics: 'OpenSans-BoldItalic.ttf'
    }
};
pdfMake.createPdf(pdfContent).download();
```

This `createPdf.js` file is linked with pdfMake library. `vfs_fonts.js` file generated using grunt `dump_dir` task with openSans font file source. I'm getting the above error! Can any one help me? thank you.